# newarray=($(echo $@)) and newarray=$@

Tags: bash

I followed an instruction which demonstrate the following codes'

```
function testit()
{ 
    local newarray 
    newarray=($(echo $@))
    echo "The new array value is: ${newarray[*]}" 
}
myarray=(1 2 3 4 5) 
echo "The original array is ${myarray[*]}" 
testit ${myarray[*]}
```

I am curious about `newarray=$(echo $@)` and the instructions's other example as `arg1=$(echo ${myarray[*]})`

`newarray=$@` is direct and intuitive, what's the benefit to take an extra effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these work properly:

```
a=($(echo $@))
b=$@
```

The first one expands `$@` *with* word splitting and globbing, so values with whitespace won't stay intact, and anything that looks like a wildcard will expand.

The second will collapse the whole array into a single scalar value with the array elements joined with spaces (Bash/ksh) or with the first character of `IFS` (Busybox/dash/Zsh; as with `"$*"`).

Conceptually, using `$@` in a scalar context also feels wrong. It's used to expand to a list of values and here we can't have one. If you do want to concatenate the array elements, I'd suggest using `s="$*"` explicitly. (The quotes help avoid bugs in some shells.)

E.g.:

```
$ touch file1 file2
$ set -- "foo  bar" "*"
$ a=($(echo $@))
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="file1" [3]="file2")
```

and

```
$ b=$@
$ declare -p b
declare -- b="foo  bar *"
```

---

A better way to make a copy of `$@` or an array is

```
c=("$@")
c=("${myarray[@]}")
```

though both of those will collapse the array indices to start from zero (note the index of `*` before and after):

```
$ unset l; l[0]="foo bar"; l[2]="*"
$ c=("${l[@]}")
$ declare -p c
declare -a c=([0]="foo bar" [1]="*")
```

That's usually not a problem, though, since you won't get arrays with nonconsecutive indices by accident.

Answer (score 0):

`newarray=$@` will assign the entire `$@` string to the single scalar variable `newarray`, not to an array.

The "command substitution" using `echo` is pointless as well. You will succeed assigning an array with `newarray=($@)` as you can see when outputting the array's element count like

```
 newarray=($@); echo "The new array value is: ${newarray[*]}, ${#newarray[@]}"
 The new array value is: 1 2 3 4 5, 5
```

as opposed to

```
newarray=$@; echo "The new array value is: ${newarray[*]}, ${#newarray[@]}"
The new array value is: 1 2 3 4 5, 1
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the essential differences between `$*`, `"$*"`, `$@`, and `"$@"`. Specifically, `newarray=($@)` is wrong.

Comment: could you please leave an answer, it works properly. @roaima

Comment: $@ is a array on  the fly.

Comment: @Sawajiri yes, and it's being used wrongly in this answer. See [Ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478398/100397) for an explanation and the correct usage. In particular notice `$@` and `"$@"`, which are very different.